# Unable to locate span elements

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I want to click the `rename` button and `del` button, but got below Exception

> Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@class="rename"]/span[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27Tll.png)"}

`@id` is dynamic, so please not use the `@id` to locate.

HTML:
[image]

Can anyone help me to figure out this problem?

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Span is not a child element of element with class `"rename"`, but it is the element with class `"rename"`, so try

```
//span[@class="rename"]
```

and

```
//span[@class="del"]
```

to locate required elements